# IE11 javascript screen resolution

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, screen-resolution, internet-explorer-11

I've a strange situation.
A simple code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    <script>
        function checkScreen()
        {
            alert(window.screen.width);
            alert(window.screen.height);
        }
        checkScreen();
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works on all browser and it show to me my screen resolution (1920x1080) but, on IE 11 it show 1812x1029.
After a search, I've not found nothing that can help me to understand why IE gets these values from js (it isn't even the viewport).
If somehone can illuminate me on this situation it will be a great help.
Thanks.

Comment: It could be because of a taskbar as well, IE then tends to adjust page views.

Comment: Are there some elements on your desktop that take up about 100px of horizontal space and 50px of vertical space, like a sidebar and a dock, that other windows can't obscure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the zoom level of IE? According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen.height),

> "Internet Explorer will take into account the zoom setting when
>   reporting the screen height. It will only return the real height of
>   the screen if the zoom is set to 100%."

Comment: it doesn't seems a zoom problem to me

Comment: MDN is correct; if the zoom is not 100%, your values will be incorrect. https://twitter.com/jonathansampson/status/410987355852386304

Comment: sure it's correct, but if it were a zoom problem, the value would be "1824" (95% of 1920) or "1728" (90% of 1920) or something similar. There is no zoom step at 1812.

Comment: @CtrlX It's possible to type in a manual zoom, it doesn't have to be at 5% increments :)

Comment: So you say that the guy has typed manually a zoom factor, add don't remember it or can't check it on his own. Pretty weird no ? Anyway, now he can check

Comment: I'm feel a bit stupid, you right... zoom was 105%! Damn, I've readed everything but I miss the zomm question.
Thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score -6):

If you use jQuery, you could use :

```
$(window).width();
$(window).height();
```

to get good size value.

Edit : Considering the comments, here is the 'non-jquery' answer :

```
var w = window,
d = document,
e = d.documentElement,
g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
width = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
height = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
alert(width);
alert(height);
```

Comment: Considering there is no jQuery tag, I consider this a poor answer

Comment: Would this give the *screen* height though? I'm thinking probably not.

Comment: Is my answer wrong ? does it worth a -4 ? please explain so I can progress

Comment: It gets the dimensions of the window, not the dimensions of the screen. It also doesn't address the question (he already knows how to get the dimensions, but wonders why IE reports inaccurate values).